# How to generate random string of predefined bytes in Java?

Tags: java, string, random, byte

I need to write a function which can generate a random string of x bytes size in Java?

for example - how can I generate a string which is 300 bytes or (+-50 bytes is also fine) in size and the encoding I will be using is `UTF-8`.

I know how to generate a random String in Java but not sure how to get random string of predefined bytes -

```
public static String generateString(Random random, String characters, int length)
{
    char[] text = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        text[i] = characters.charAt(random.nextInt(characters.length()));
    }
    return new String(text);
}
```

Comment: It is impossible. UTF-8 is multibyte encoding, so if you add a random byte to existing sequence, you get potentially invalid code-point. To keep resulting string valid, you have to stick with characters, not bytes.

Comment: Another alternative is to  use single-byte encoding.

Comment: @Basilevs I got your point, Is there any way of generating random string of 300 bytes in size? I don't care about UTF-8 encoding now.

Comment: Just use any single byte encoding to decode an array of 300 random bytes.

Comment: BTW, you do know, that string length is measured in characters, not bytes, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it's fairly simple. You can use a `StringBuilder` to randomly append characters selected from your input alphabet. Something like,

```
public static String generateString(Random random, String characters,
        int length) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sb.append(characters.charAt(random.nextInt(characters.length())));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you call it with a `String characters`, like

```
String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String characters = "0123456789" + abc + abc.toUpperCase() + "{}[]()";
```

I think you'll get the human readable kind of output you seek.

Comment: Thanks Elliott for the suggestion but what I need is generate a  random string of 300 bytes? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. 300 bytes of what alphabet? byte 0 to byte 255? Build such a string and it won't be printable, but you could do it.